# Android - ListAdapter doesn't work

Tags: android

I get this problem when I run my Android App. My code is quite simple:

```
public void dettagliolista(String listapassata){

    List<String> elenco = Arrays.asList(listapassata.split(","));
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listrow,elenco);
    Log.v(TAG,String.valueOf(itemsAdapter.getCount()));
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dettaglioLista);
    Log.v(TAG,String.valueOf(elenco.size()));
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    Log.v(TAG,String.valueOf(listView.getChildCount()));
    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.v(TAG,String.valueOf(listView.getChildCount()));
}
```

I get this output:
3
3
0
0

So, my Adapter's size is 3, my List size is 3, but when I bind my adapter to my listview I get 0 children. Maybe I did a silly error, but in this moment I can't see it.

Thank you in advance

listview XML

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/dettaglioLista" 
android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" 
android:divider="#CCCCCC" android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
android:paddingLeft="2dp" > </ListView>
```

listrow XML

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/tvName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: my listview doesn' t show anything (I'll edit my post to make it more clear), even if the list I passed has three elements

Comment: can you please post ListView and List Item xml ?

Comment: Have to post inside question not as comment.

Comment: Solved by Simas :) It was because of that "0dp", now it works perfectly. Still I don't get why I get "0" after notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listView.getChildCount` returns 0 because you're calling it too early.

Your list view appears empty probably because its width or height is incorrect. Instead use `match_parent` or fixed dimension like 200dp.

Comment: Yes! Now it works. Still I don't get why I get "0" after notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @GrandePuffo because it counts visible views.

Answer (score 0):

try using simple_list_item_1 for second parameter for ArrayAdapter